# Opening a dialog autocloses panel

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQM panel that holds a selectmenu.

When you open the panel and click on the menu, the dialog opens.
Now if you choose an option, you will return to the page and the panel will be closed.
Is there a way to keep the panel open?

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szFzP/).

```html
<div id="panel" data-role="panel">
    <select id="select" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="1">text</option>
        ...
        <option value="9">text</option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/szFzP/1/ use `$(document).on('pagehide', '#select-dialog', function () {
    $('#panel').panel('open');
});`

Comment: Thank you Omar for this working solution!
Although I still wonder if it can be prevented from closing rather than reopening it.

Comment: What causes the panel to close is the dialog. Because dialogs are treated like pages, so when you open a dialog you leave the page to another page but with `data-rel=dialog`. Even `data-dismissible="false"` doesn't force the panel to remain open. However, you can also force panel to open on `pageshow` if you want.

Answer (score 3):

What causes the panel to close is the dialog. Because dialogs are treated like pages, so when you open a dialog you leave the page to another page but with `data-rel='dialog'`.

Even `data-dismissible='false'` doesn't force the panel to remain open. However, you can also force panel to open on `pageshow` or once the dialog disappears `pagehide`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/szFzP/1/)**

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '#select-dialog', function () {
 $('#panel').panel('open');
});
```

Comment: Great solution, upvoted. FWIW, I found that binding on the event `pagebeforehide` works a bit better -- it triggers earlier than `pagehide` and the panel is fully opened by the time the screen has transitioned back to the original page. With `pagehide` there was a second delay when the original page had loaded, but the panel was not yet open.

Comment: @ElliotB. If you're using jQM 1.4, this might malfunction as page events are replaced with pagecontainer events. This solution is meant for jQM 1.3 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Following up ot @Omar's suggestion, I had to add a trigger() method to get the panel to open. So: `$('#panel').panel('open').trigger();`